# Client Server Authentication

Tags: c#, sockets, authentication, client, communication

I am creating a client server communication based on Asynchronous Sockets, my client will send the username and password to the server then the server will replay whether the account is valid, so i want to secure this steps so no one could record the conversation and keep sending it to my client to achieve illegal entry to the secret data

[The Question {Simplified}] How to securely authenticate the client to the server ... ?

[NOTE] I know SSL but i cant afford paying for a certificate so i need a free alternative to provide secure communication between my client and server.

Comment: How do you host the server application? IIS?

Comment: Kerberos? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29

Comment: its a socket listener... not using IIS.

Comment: I seem to recall something about the man who invents his own server security having a fool for a client.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As always, the most secure password is the one, that the server doesn't know, and that is never transmitted. So what you could do is:

- On the server, store the username, a random salt ("account salt") and a secure hash of the salted password ("server shared secret").
- On login, in a first step let the client transmit only the username (not secret)
- The server should reply with the account salt (not secret) and a randomly generated session salt (not secret). It is important, that the **server** generates the session salt.
- On the client, salt the password with the account salt and hash it (keep this as " client shared secret"), then salt the result with the session salt and hash it again. Transmit this as an authentication token (not secret)
- On the server, take the salted hash from your DB, salt it with the session salt and hash it - if this matches the authentication token, the connection is authenticated. (Client is authenticated to server)
- if you want to additionaly authenticate the server to the client, you repeat the procedure: Client generates a salt, server creates token from it by salting/hashing the stored secret.
- If you want to authenticate the single requests (not only the connection), salt them with the shared secret and hash them, send this as a per-request authentication field. Since in a valid login server shared secret and client shared secret are identical,both sides should come to the same result, thus verifying the authentication field.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I misread, but I think the OP was asking about connection security. That said, all that you say is goodness, but I'd still rather have this problem outsourced and let an existing, known-secure library handle this for me.

Comment: II read correctly, the question was: "How to securely authenticate the client to the server" - this is achieved by my suggestion. Ofcourse I don't achieve connection confidentiality (and I didn't think it was asked for). As for using a library: I understand that, but I am not 100% convinced: Any library used would need to be trusted if not to defeat the purpouse - and this can be quite a challenge, if you rule out SSL as the OP did.

Comment: It comes down to odds to me. Do you think the OP will do it as well as, say, Microsoft did in the base CLR implementation? I'm skeptical.

Comment: @EricFleischman Good point well made, Sir +1! I am in no position (or willing) to judge the OP's potential implementation. The reason why I only use very simple steps (concatenation and hashing) in my suggested procedure, which happens to be my standard way of doing this sort of thing (short of TLS or friends), is to make a correct implementation more likely. Ofcourse I have abstracted into a library for my use in a lot of languages, so as to not have to reinvent the wheel every time. For my personal taste, this makes me more comfortable than using an unverifiable 3rd party lib. Tastes differ.

Comment: As a dev lead, I used to have rules of thumb for my devs. One of them was "if you find yourself implementing crypto, you're doing something wrong & it won't get through code review." I later refined crypto to include key exchanges, secret exchanges or anything even remotely related. :) (Sadly, this refinement was reactive, not proactive)

Comment: i got lost in alot of hashing processes :D but i will try and tell you what results i came across...

Comment: As I said: Tastes differ. It is not my intention to convince you or even argue you. For you, trust in a third party lib works better, for me trust in my or my devs own code (or code reviewed by them or me) works better. Both arguments have their merits, I am the last to dispute yours.

Comment: @TorlanOther Go one step at the time, you only need concatenation and hashing. Both are nativly supported in C#/.Net or alternativly available as open source libs.

Comment: This is given: A MITM doesn't have the knowledge to produce the auth tokens given by the client (attacking the server) and whatever the client sends to it, it can't use it to recover the PW. If you want to assure the client, that the server is really the server (attacking the client), you have to repeat the process in the other direction (client generates session salt), so that the client can verify the server's knowledge.

Comment: The sketch I just uploaded doesn't have the server verification step.

Comment: no i am worry about fooling the client with the Login OK packet to get into the program ... am i understand you wrong ?

Comment: You want to assure to the client, that the server is really who he says he is?

Comment: yea that is what i want to do .. making sure that my client is connected to my server [ not any other fake ones ]

Comment: I updated the sketch in my answer with this reverse step: In the first step the client creates a client salt. In the last 2 steps, the server creates a token from it, which the client can verify. This assures 1. the server, that the client knows the (salted/hashed) PW and 2. it assures the client, that the server knows the salted/hashed PW. A MITM does not have this knowledge, and it is never sent over the wire.

Comment: so doing this steps can make me sure that the user only logins with a valid id and password

Comment: The complete procedure guarantees both: 1. The Server is assured, that the client knows the password, so the client is authenticated to the server, and 2. the client is assured, that the server knows the salted/hashed password, so the server is authenticated to the client. In effect you can be sure, that the server is the real server and the client knows the passowrd.

Comment: OH sorry what you mean but the account salt !

Comment: I'm impressed by the depth of the thread. :) Eugen, perhaps a good way to go from here would be to blog an "open source" protocol that you propose and open it up for criticism from the public? Then others could reference it as a solution to the problem in the future.
If you want me to review before you publish feel free to email me...you can get to me via the website in my profile.

Comment: @TorlanOther The "account salt" is part of what you store in your user database - see the first bullet in my answer. It is the salt that is used to hash the PW before storing the result.

Comment: @EricFleischman I really appreciate your comment, thank you very much. Actually I was thinking of that and a bit more: I have (interoperable) implementations in C#, JS and PHP as libs for our internal use. I must check, if there are legal obstacles, but I am ofcourse willing to opensource them. Would you review the C# code (in addition to the protocol itself)?

Comment: Happy to. Fire my way. Email address is on my website.

Comment: Eugen sorry there is another thing which idk if i misunderstood . Where is the part which the server notifies the client whether the login credentials are valid or not, and if it exists in your answer, is it vulnerable to replay attack so someone could record it and sends it to the client in another time ?

Also i am planing to include unix time stamp in my messages, to know whether this packet is old one or not ... is it a safe method ?

Comment: And you say in step 4 that i salt the USERNAME ? why i salt the username after i send it in the first time ? and how could i compare a hashed username with hashed password !. Do you mean in step 4 that i salt the password or you mean the username and i misunderstood you ? 
Also the picture differs from what you said above it what is the client salt presented in the picture ?

Comment: What i understand now is that you want me to do something like this

1-The client connects to the server, sending in the user-name (but not password)
2-The server responds by sending out unique random number
3-The client encrypts that random number using the hash of their password as the key
4-The client sends the encrypted random number to the server
5-The server encrypts the random number with the correct hash of the user's password
6-The server compares the two encrypted random numbers                        .But how could i notify the client that the login info are correct !?.

Comment: Sorry for the many questions :D but there is another question... could some one simulate the whole process to get access to the client (the client will have some info that i don't want someone to steal them). Like someone loop my client connection to his fake server and do the same process with it to fool the client ?... i am thinking of using a static key to encrypt all the whole process in it [ stored in the client ]

Comment: @TorlanOther 1. The server tells the client "OK" in the last arrow, after checking (`=?`) the token ("Authenticated"). 2. It is not vulnerable to replay, as the server creates the session salt and the client the client salt. 3. Ofcourse you use the PASSWORD, not the USERNAME, was a typo 4. the difference is, that with bullet 5 you also have server auth, not only client auth. 5. I don't use encryption, just concatenation and hashing 6. NEVER EVER store a key in the software

Comment: Do you mind giving me your email address ?. i'd really love to have only 10 minutes from your very valuable time to have a small communication about the whole thing

Comment: I am so sorry if requesting your mail maybe annoyed you, but it's just that you are the only one who understands exactly what i want to achieve

Comment: @TorlanOther You didn't annoy me - but it defeats the purpose of this site! Ask your questions, I'll try to answer

Comment: i now understand the whole thing EXCEPT the last part how could i tell the client that auth is ok... Someone maybe record the auth ok packet and send it to the client in another time ? right !... Also in step 5 "take the salted hash from your DB" you mean the securely hashed salted password ??. Also i did not get the part of authenticating the client to server.. the last 2 steps

Comment: And what about the Account salt is it generated and saved in the databse [OnUserRegister]? static one you mean

Comment: Yes. It is a random value per user, stored in the database. The reason we need it is to thwart offline computation attack on the hash of the password.

Comment: The packet, that tells the client "OK" also has the server token, which is made from the random client salt - so it will be correct ONLY for the case, where the client generated and sent exactly this salt. On the next login, the client will generate another salt, and the paket must now have another server token. This is replay-proof, as long as the salt is non-repeating.

Comment: but what if someone created a fake server to handle the whole process with my client... how could i prevent this too

Comment: The fake server would need to know your password or at least the stored secret (=salted and hashed password). If he doesn't know it, he can not calculate the server token from the client salt. The client would see a wrong server token.

Comment: Why would he need to know my password he can use any account with his fake server ?!. just to get access to the client my worry is about the client now i don't any one to use it without a legal account. So simulating the server might get the hacker access to my client with any fake account !

Comment: You mean the scenario, where somebody points your client to a fake server **on purpouse** ? This is no risk - there must be **never be anything of value** in the client. The moment you give your client to others, you lost control over it - you can not rely on anything in it to stay confidential.

Comment: Let's say that i am as example developing an online game... and i want all players to pay for account to play it... so i don't some one to point my game to his fake server and make a private server for it !. NOTE : this is only an example you can say i am developing any kind of functional program that i want people to pay for account [monthly] to have access to it

Comment: In this case, you asked the wrong question: You don't need a secure auth mechanism, you need a DRM scheme. Mind though, that the first rule of DRM is: DRM doesn't work

Comment: what ? srry i didn't get that at all. and is this DRM protects any kind of applications from getting a private\fake server

Comment: You could at least create your game in a way that it needs information from your server. THis will stop the casual non-paying users, but not the hardcore crackers.

Comment: If your Scheme is to protect the **client** from use with other servers, you are in effect creating a DRM-protected program.

Comment: I.e. a program that can not be used without your consent.

Comment: Mentioning the game i was telling as example but my application will not be a game its just an personal accountant application which i need users to pay monthly fees to use it !

Comment: Whatever it is, you want the program to be usable only with your consent. This is the definition of DRM - with all its disadvantages. You could design your program so, that major parts (e.g. the accounting rules) are performed on the server, not the client. This way you don't need to protect the client. You need to protect the logon, but this is solved here.

Comment: So i will try to do a test work of what i understood from you and how some functions are done on the server, then send the work to you to test how secure is it ? do you mind do me that favor because i am not good at securing programs so i wanna someone who tests my work and rate it before i release it to the public

Comment: There is something wrong i think if i came to compare the value that is hashed with the session salt with the one stored in the DB [which was salted with different salt ] they must be different ! or am i wrong

Comment: Here is my function to generate Salted Hash static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(byte[] plainText, byte[] salt)
 {
     HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

     byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes =
       new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];

     for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
     {
         plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainText[i];
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length; i++)
     {
         plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainText.Length + i] = salt[i];
     }
     return algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);
 }

Comment: Look at the sketch: Both sides calculate `authtoken=hash(sessionsalt+secret)`. On the server side, the `secret=hash(accountsalt+password)` stored in the DB, on the client side `secret=hash(accountsalt+password)` with the password given by the user and the accountsalt from the DB. They are identical. Your function looks good.

Comment: Eugen do you know about ssl ?

Comment: Ofcourse: It is what you ruled out in your OQ! If you need info about SSL, you should open a new question.

Comment: @EugenRieck: Have you created a blog post for this?

Comment: No, I haven't - the point being, that Stack Overflow is searchable and has much more google juice than my blog would ever have. Is there any information, that you still miss here, that I could provide?

Answer (score 4):

I typically tell people that if they find themselves doing crypto themselves they are inventing security problems. :) The odds are good you're missing edge cases. I would suggest relying on something that exists already and has been heavily secured.

If you're using managed sockets, there is a version of the stream class that does crypto for you (NegotiateStream). I would suggest starting there and seeing if it can do what you need w/o you having to invent your own.

Comment: OTOH outsourcing crypto and security to a third-party library (maybe even one you can't verify on the source level) might need an exceptional level of trust.

Comment: Fair. I would start by trying to use a built-in crypto library within the MSFT stack (managed preferred given the application). These are very well secured and used by other MSFT products. They have had tremendous security attention.

Comment: is NegotiateStream secure enough so i can rely on it to handle all my data.[note] i dont anyone to get access to my server without a legal permission because the database will contain a crucial info. i want to make sure that the client connects only to my server

Comment: I don't feel qualified to answer that authoritatively. It depends upon your needs and how you use NegotiateStream. I can say it's a great starting point vs. building your own. :)

Comment: My program will be publicly released and i am very worry about getting my program cracked, because its database will contain crucial info so you must provide me with the best authentication method to make sure atleast 90% that my clients are safe from any hacker

Comment: It's super hard for me to say what you should do with authority. So much depends upon what is reasonable for your product, what OS requirements you have, what keys you have to work with, what user experience assumptions are reasonable, and so on.
Generally speaking, I would be looking for off-the-shelf solutions, not stuff you have to roll on your own. Rolling your own secure channel will end in tears. You want something that is known secure.

I'm sorry I can't say if NegotiateStream is that thing. I would look in to it, in to SSL, in to WCF (and the security bindings it offers), and others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of public and symmetric keys in order to secure authentication.

First send a public key for the client to send his authentication data encrypted in. If the data is valid, you could then have the client generate his own public key, and have both send symmetric keys to each other via each other's public key.

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was posted a few years ago, but I thought that I would add my own two cents here now. Things have changed in the last couple of year. This might help some one else.

I do not want to take anything away from Eugen, excellent work.

The best way to encrypt the traffic between your client and your server is still using SSL/TLS. You can now get free licenses from https://letsencrypt.org/.

It sounds like you already had SSL figured out, so I would plug in with the free certs that you get from the above link

Good luck, 
- Andrew